# Create pivot table from DataFrame with value columns on the "bottom"

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pivot-table

There is a dataframe:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({
    'A': ['A1','A1','A1','A1','A2','A2','A2','A2'],
    'B': ['B1','B1','B2','B2','B3','B3','B4','B4'],
    'C': ['one','two','one','two','one','two','one','two'],
    'D': [0, 0, np.nan, 1, 0, np.nan, 1, 1],
    'E': [1, 1, np.nan, 1, 0, np.nan, 1, 1]
})
```

So, as a table it looks like this:

[image]

I try to group it by `A` and `B` and move column `C` to header, so columns will rename to `('one', 'D'), ('one', 'E'), ('two', 'D'), ('two', 'E')` and it will take the following look:

[image]

To achieve this I tried `pivot_table` and `group + unstack` methods:

```py
# Method 1
df.pivot_table(index=['A', 'B'], columns='C', values=['D', 'E'], aggfunc='sum', fill_value=0)

# Method 2
df.groupby(['A', 'B', 'C']).agg('sum').unstack(level=['D', 'E'])
```

Both methods return me the same result, where values as column names are at the very top:

[image]

How can columns layers be moved or pivot table created with values on the very low column level?

Or more precise question: how to get dataframe from image 2 instead of dataframe from image 3 from `df`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If using pivoting is possible add [`DataFrame.swaplevel`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.swaplevel.html) and [`DataFrame.sort_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_index.html):

```
df = (df.pivot_table(index=['A', 'B'], 
                     columns='C', 
                     values=['D', 'E'], 
                     aggfunc='sum', fill_value=0)
        .swaplevel(axis=1)
        .sort_index(axis=1))
print (df)
C     one    two   
        D  E   D  E
A  B               
A1 B1   0  1   0  1
   B2   0  0   1  1
A2 B3   0  0   0  0
   B4   1  1   1  1
```

Or if use aggregation `sum` is possible use [`DataFrame.stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) with [`Series.unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.unstack.html):

```
df = (df.groupby(['A', 'B', 'C']).sum()
        .stack()
        .unstack([-2,-1])
        )
print (df)
C      one       two     
         D    E    D    E
A  B                     
A1 B1  0.0  1.0  0.0  1.0
   B2  0.0  0.0  1.0  1.0
A2 B3  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
   B4  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0
```